# Using Function.prototype.apply to set javascript callback scope

Tags: javascript, scope, apply

It's frustrating to have to manually set the scope of an object every time I declare a callback in JavaScript, but it's a fact of life. I wondered if I could do it by passing [mycallback].apply as the callback, and the scope object as an argument, like so:

```
var f = function() { console.log(this.x); };
var o = {x: 3};
setTimeout(f.apply, 1000, o);
```

As far as I can tell, this should call f with o as the scope, but instead Chrome gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on [object DOMWindow], which is a object and not a function". Why doesn't this work?

Comment: who the hell carpet-bombed all of our answers with downvotes?

Comment: @Travis - I think your answer is fine; it just misses the point. @MooGoo's answer actually explains that the association with `f` is lost, which is the best answer.

Comment: Anyone who doubts you can pass native functions around to other functions as arguments should try this: `Function.prototype.apply.apply.call(Function.prototype.apply, function(t) { alert(t) }, [this, ["test"]]);`

Comment: @lwburk yep you're right. I went for the solution, instead of the "why"

Comment: You probably want `f.bind(o)` (not available in all browsers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the same reason you need to "set the scope" in the first place. Only the `apply` function is sent to `setTimeout`, its association with function `f` is lost. Thus Javascript assigns the global object, `window`, to `this`, as it would in any other case.

It is interesting to note that `apply`, while being a native function, is not special or magical in some way, and behaves in a way consistent to user defined functions in the setting of the `this` variable.

Comment: Oh! Right. Duh. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

@MooGoo's answer is correct, but perhaps more explanation is needed.

When you call the function `apply` on `f` like this:

```
f.apply(ctx, args);
```

...then you're executing `apply` in the context of `f`.

But when you pass a reference to `apply` to a function, like this:

```
setTimeout(f.apply, 1000, o);
```

...that's all you're doing: passing a reference to the function `f.apply`. This is equivalent to passing `Function.prototype.apply` because:

```
console.log(f.apply === Function.prototype.apply); // true
```

Any connection to `f` is lost in `window.setTimeout`. It receives a reference to the generic `apply` function of `Function.prototype`. Nothing more. No context.

Therefore, as in any other case where an explicit context is not set, the `apply` function is called with `window` as its context object.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var f = function() { console.log(this.x); };
var o = {x: 3};
setTimeout(function(){f.apply(o)}, 1000);
```

Works for me.

Set timeout expects a function. But since apply is a built in function and you can not see the native code behind it, it may not act as a "function" object.

Comment: What in the world could it possibly mean to say, "Passing params to setTimeout is very sketchy"? Its behavior is well-defined.

Comment: eek, a bit of an exaggeration on my part. It is well defined, sketchy as in it doesn't behave as you would expect, by observation.

Comment: I get a console log of 3. How does this alter the context?